# Lines look irregular in thickness when using TextureBrush

Tags: c#, gdi+

I intend to draw lines of the same thickness by using Texture Brush.
However the lines' thickness look irregular.

I'd like not to stop draw by 0.1mm unit if I can.
Because user's code is almost done.

I'd appreciate it if you have ideas.

[The lines in display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1UNK.jpg)

```
    //Brush User's Code
    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // I need to draw by 0.1mm unit like CAD.
        e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
        e.Graphics.PageScale = 0.1F;

        Point leftTop = new Point(2, 2);
        using(TextureBrush aBrush = myBrush()){
            aBrush.TranslateTransform(leftTop.X, leftTop.Y);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(aBrush, leftTop.X,leftTop.Y, 90, 1000);
        }
    }

    //BrushMaker Code
    private  TextureBrush myBrush()
    {

        Bitmap bitmapCanvas = new Bitmap(20, 10);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapCanvas);

        Pen myPen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 2F);
        g.DrawLine(myPen, 2, 5, 18, 5);

        var brush = new TextureBrush(bitmapCanvas);

        myPen.Dispose();
        g.Dispose();
        bitmapCanvas.Dispose();

        return brush;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing is blurry because `e.Graphics.PageScale` is different from 1. When drawing on screen you really must use only `GraphicsUnit.Pixel` and all other values must be converted to pixels.

Since the convention is that all monitors have 96 pixels per inch, and by definition 1 inch == 25.4 mm, we have that 0.1 mm == 0.1 mm * 96 (px / inch) * (1 inch / 25.4 mm) == 0.378 pixels (approximately). Let's make it 0.4 pixels as basic unit. Convert all your numbers in the code by multiplying them with 0.4. Instead of `Point(2, 2)` it's `Point(1, 1)`. `90, 1000` becomes `36, 400`. `Bitmap(20, 10)` is now `Bitmap(8, 4)`. `2F` and `2, 5, 18, 5` become `1F` and `1, 2, 7, 2`.

After all this image will not be blurry anymore. The price you pay is that 0.4 is not exactly 0.378 (actually 0.3779527559...), so, everything will appear 5.5% larger, but no one will notice that.

Comment: I suggest using `e.Graphics.DpiX/Y;` instead of assuming 96dpi. Other than that: Yes, one can't expect that 10pixel will always fit into the pixelgrid when using a graphicsunit other than pixel..

Comment: Thank you, Dialecticus and TaW. I understand why my code draws blurry lines. I've intended to my code can apply both screen and printing. I may have to correct my code. I've already written a tons of code, especially brush user's code. It may be a tough work. 
I appreciate your answer. I've learned a lot.

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please consider consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..! - I see that you have never done this: Go the the (invisible) checkmark at the top left, below the votes of the answer and click it! It turns green and gains both the author and you a little reputation..